# How to remove blue background color around button in windows phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I am developing app for windows phone 8.1, I have used some buttons with red background color in my app.
Blue background color coming while clicking on button.
I'd like to remove blue background color of button in windows phone
This background color coming when I click on the button.

How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That blue color is probably the  default themecolor of the phone.So to change that right click on the button on designer and edit the copy and change the background value for the button in pressed state to whatever you want. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Add following line in you app.xaml file

```
<Application.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonPressedForegroundThemeBrush"  Color="Transparent" />
</Application.Resources>
```